# Keras accuracy metrics differ from manual computation

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

I am working on a binary classification problem on Keras. The loss function I use is `binary_crossentropy` and metrics is `metrics=['accuracy']`. Since two classes are imbalanced, I use `class_weight='auto'` when I fit training data set to the model.

To see the performance, I print out the accuracy by

`print GNN.model.test_on_batch([test_sample_1, test_sample_2], test_label)[1]`

The output is `0.973`. But this result is different when I use following lines to get the prediction accuracy

```py
predict_label = GNN.model.predict([test_sample_1, test_sample_2])
rounded = predict_label.round(1)
print (rounded == test_label).sum()/float(rounded.shape[0])
```

which is `0.953`.

So I am wondering how `metrics=['accuracy']` evaluate the model performance and why the result is different.

For details, I attached the model summary below.

[image]

```py
input_size = self.n_feature
encoder_size = 2000
dropout_rate = 0.5
X1 = Input(shape=(input_size, ), name='input_1')
X2 = Input(shape=(input_size, ), name='input_2')

encoder = Sequential()
encoder.add(Dropout(dropout_rate, input_shape=(input_size, )))
encoder.add(Dense(encoder_size, activation='tanh'))

encoded_1 = encoder(X1)
encoded_2 = encoder(X2)
merged = concatenate([encoded_1, encoded_2])

comparer = Sequential()
comparer.add(Dropout(dropout_rate, input_shape=(encoder_size * 2, )))

comparer.add(Dense(500, activation='relu'))
comparer.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
comparer.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))
comparer.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
comparer.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

Y = comparer(merged)

model = Model(inputs=[X1, X2], outputs=Y)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
self.model = model
```

And I train model by

```py
self.hist = self.model.fit(
               x=[train_sample_1, train_sample_2],
               y=train_label,
               class_weight = 'auto',
               validation_split=0.1,
               batch_size=batch_size,
               epochs=epochs,
               callbacks=callbacks)
```

Comment: The training dataset only has two labels including `1` and `0`.

Comment: What about if you do (in pseudo-code) something like `predict = argmax(predict_label)` and calculate accuracy as `(predict == argmax(test_label)).sum() / float(predict.shape[0])`?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to find the index of the maximum value of predict_label and test_label. Your suggestion looks like `(predict_label.argmax() == test_label.argmax()).sum()/float(predict_label.argmax().shape[0])`, which won't work.

Comment: If your predictions are logits (network's belief that the input lies in each of two categories in your case), and you have true labels `[1 0]` or `[0 1]`, you might have corresponding network outputs, if not softmaxed, of `[100 50]` and `[1 10]`, which would definitely not round to the same as your expected labels, but the maximum indices of each label and prediction would be the same (in this example). `predict_label.argmax().shape[0] == predict_label.shape[0]` is, I assume, the number of examples in your batch.

Comment: Wait, if your output is softmaxed then it has more than one element, otherwise it's just always 1. `softmax(x)_i = e^(x_i) / sum(e^(x_i))` which is `e^x / e^x == 1` if you only have one output. So you have a single output, or you have a softmax output. If you have a single output maybe it's run through a sigmoid function, which squashes it between 0 and 1? If multiple, I'd recommend the argmax approach if each sample can only take one class.

Comment: Can you post your `model.summary()` to check the actual output shapes? It seems funny to have a softmax with only one output and yet have different accuracy values...It would be also useful to print `test_label.max()` and `test_label.min()`, and also `predict_label.max()` and `predict_label.min()`.

Comment: Sorry guys. I use `sigmoid` as the activation function for the output layer. Sorry for confusing.

Comment: The results of `test_label.max()`, `test_label.min()`, `predict_label.max()` and `predict_label.min()` are `1.0`, `0.0`, `1.0` and `0.0` respectively.